# jBPM : Can a signalEvent on ksession be signalled for a process which is started after calling the signalEvent method?

Tags: jbpm

I have a requirement to start multiple instances of the same jbpm process for different i/ps which I will call an "event" which can run for hours. I also have a requirement to be able to "Abort" the event at any point, especially if it has been long running.
Assuming the system will trigger the multiple instances of the process as resources free up and the `ksession.signalEvent` is called at any random point of time when some processes are in progress, and some processes are not even started since the system did not have free resources, will the signalled Event be conveyed by the session to the processes which will be started much after the call to `ksession.signalEvent()`? Any clarification about this will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot signal a process instance that has not been started yet. Events are treated as point in time, that means that when the event is fired is catches by all the interested in that particular event. If there is no one listening (in this case the process that hasn't (being started yet) the event will be missed and that's the expected behaviour. 
It seems that you are trying to model with events something that requires a different solution.

HTH